# Given $a^2 \equiv n\pmod q$ find $b$ such that $b^2 \equiv n\pmod {q^2}$

Tags: hensels-lemma

Given $a^2 \equiv n\pmod q$ find $b$ such that $b^2 \equiv n\pmod {q^2}$

$a,n,q$ are given. How to find $b$?

I know I am supposed to use Hensel's lemma and "lifting" $q$, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: you mean $\pmod {q^2}$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes! Fixing, tnx

Comment: Let $b=kq+a$ and solve for $k$ in $(kq+a)^2\equiv n \pmod {q^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something of the form $b=a+kq\bmod q^2$. You want
$$(a+kq)^2\equiv n\pmod{q^2}\Leftrightarrow a^2+2akq\equiv n\pmod{q^2}.$$
So, you're going to want to choose $k$ so that
$$k\equiv \frac{n-a^2}{2aq}\bmod q.$$
You may notice that we're given that $q|n-a^2$, but there's not necessarily an extra factor of $2$ or a factor of $a$. For $a$, Hensel's lemma will fail for $b\equiv 0\bmod q$ if it's not a multiple of $q^2$, and for $2$, Hensel's lemma in fact fails for this polynomial when $q=2$, so dividing by $2$ modulo $q$ is not an issue.

Comment: It's not working for me for some reason. For $n=643211,q=7,a=4$, I calculated $k$ to be $45942$ but $(kq+a)^2$ is not equal to $n$ mod $q^2$

Comment: @IlyaGazman Sorry -- I'd made a typo. It should work now.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut continuing with my example, I am getting that $n-a^2$ is not divisible by $2aq$ $643211 mod 2*7*4 = 35$

Comment: @IlyaGazman You need to perform the division of $2a$ modulo $q$; so, in your example, $n-a^2=643195$, and $\frac{n-a^2}{q}=91885$, Now, you need to calculate $91885/8$ modulo $7$, which is the same as multiplying by the multiplicative inverse of $8$. This inverse is $1$, so you get $k=91885\equiv 3\bmod 7$.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You know that $a^2\equiv n+sq \mod q^2$, for some integer $s$.

Thus for any integer $r$ we have $$(a+rq)^2\equiv n+sq+2arq \mod q^2.$$

To find $r$ such that $(a+rq)^2 \equiv n \mod q^2$ you must solve $2ar\equiv-s \mod q$.

This will have a solution precisely if $\gcd(2a,q)|s$.  In particular if $q$ is a prime not equal to $2$ and $q\not\!|a$ this will have a solution.